# Email account deleted and 2.69 GB still showing up

Tags: email

I deleted my email account on my iPhone 6 because it has 2.69 GB of mail and attachments. The 2.69 still shows up with the deleted email account. What can I do to regain the storage?

I also rebooted the phone. It acted up when I shot an 11 minute video and tried emailing it.

Comment: Try restarting your phone. This may help clear out the data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your Drafts folder? The email draft with the video attachment should be there. Try to delete that specific email draft.